# as3 socket with multi thread or background process in as3 socket

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, sockets, flex-mobile

my project using flex mobile 4.5 using socket .. receive huge data stream..
and ui application like hang... in minute before all process data complete
and how to do with multi thread in socket in as3 ? any axamples ?
any trick? to make  background process

bellow my code

---

```
            private var workQueue:Array = new Array();

            /**************** VARIABLES ************************/
            [Bindable]public var defauldSocketIP:String ="119.99.67.168";
            [Bindable]public var defauldPort:Number = 9090;
            [Bindable]public var heartbeatTime:Number = 1000 * 60;
            [Bindable]public var limitLivetrade:Number = 30;
            [Bindable]public var sessionid:String;
            [Bindable]public var userid:String;
            [Bindable]public var password:String;
            [Bindable]public var msgdata:String;
            [Bindable]public var busyIndicator:Boolean = false;
            [Bindable]public var livetradeData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            [Bindable]public var IndicesSectoralData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            [Bindable]public var topGainerBrokerData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            [Bindable]public var brokerData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            [Bindable]public var stockData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(); 
            [Bindable]public var marketChartData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(); 
            /* best Quote */
            [Bindable]public var bestQuoteDataA:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            [Bindable]public var bestQuoteDataB:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            [Bindable]public var bestQuoteBID:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            [Bindable]public var bestQuoteOFFER:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            [Bindable]public var bestQuoteTFREQ:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            [Bindable]public var stockSummarayData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            /* end of best Quote */
            [Bindable]public var tempDataSocket:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            [Bindable]public var sTemp:int = new int();
            [Bindable]public var db:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            [Bindable]public var curentCode:String;//current code for unscribe
            /**************** Socket        ********************/
            private var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            public var _data:ByteArray;

            [Bindable]public var websocketData:String;
            [Bindable]public var isLogin:Boolean = false;
            public var flipTrans:FlipViewTransition = new FlipViewTransition();

    \
                   /* socket connection */
            public var socket : Socket;

            public function init() : void {
                //navigator.defaultPushTransition = new FlipViewTransition();
                socket = new Socket();
                socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
                socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onSocketClose);
                socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onSocketData);
                socket.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError ); 
                socket.addEventListener( SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSEC_ERRORError );

                /****************** INTERVAL FOR PING SERVER *************/
                var myInterval:uint = setInterval (heartbeat, heartbeatTime);
                //clearInterval(myInterval);
                if(isLogin){
                    flipTrans.duration = 1000; 
                    flipTrans.mode = FlipViewTransitionMode.CARD;
                    flipTrans.direction =  ViewTransitionDirection.RIGHT;
                    mainview.pushView(MainView,null,null,flipTrans);
                }
                /****************** Database setup           *************/
                initDB();
                if(db.length == 0){ createDefauldConfig(); } 

            }
            /**************** menus        ********************/

            /**************** alert information box *********************/
            protected function alertSoketError():void
            {
                Alert.show(this, Alert.IC_INFO, "Information", "Sorry cannot connect to server please contact administrator.");
            }
            /**************** inquotes database      ********************/
            public var sqlConnection:SQLConnection;



                public function onSEC_ERRORError( errorEvent:SecurityErrorEvent ):void 
                { 
                busyIndicator = false;
                isLogin = false;
                mainview.pushView(login);
                trace( "onSEC_ERRORError: " + errorEvent ); 
                alertSoketError();
                }
                public function onSocketClose(e:Event,reconect:Boolean = true):void{                             resetData();
                    socket.close();
                    mainview.pushView(login);
                trace("socket Closed");
                if(reconect){
                reconnect();
                }

                }
                public function onIOError( errorEvent:IOErrorEvent ):void 
                { 
                busyIndicator = false;
                isLogin = false;
                mainview.pushView(login);
                trace( "IOError: " + errorEvent.text ); 
                alertSoketError();
                }
                public function onConnect(event : Event) : void {
                trace("login|"+userid+"|"+(MD5.hash(password)));
                sendData("login|"+userid+"|"+(MD5.hash(password)));
                }
                public function getFormattedTime(t:int):String
                {   
                var s:String = new String();
                var hour:String = t.toString().substr(0,2);
                var minute:String = t.toString().substr(2,2);
                var scn:String = t.toString().substr(4,5);
                return s  =hour+":"+minute+":"+scn;
                }

                public function checkTipe(data:String):void{
                var split:Array = spliter.doSplit(data,"|");
                    /*Login */

                if(split[0]=="login" && split[1]=="ok" && isLogin == false){
                    trace("split[0]"+split[0]+"-split[1]"+split[1]+"isLogin =="+isLogin);

                sessionid = new String();
                sessionid = split[2];
                isLogin = true;
                flipTrans.duration = 1000; 
                flipTrans.mode = FlipViewTransitionMode.CARD;
                flipTrans.direction =  ViewTransitionDirection.RIGHT;
                mainview.pushView(MainView,null,null,flipTrans);
                sendData("subscribe|"+sessionid+"|4|0");
                sendData("subscribe|"+sessionid+"|3|0");
                sendData("subscribe|"+sessionid+"|5|0");
                }
                /*Login fail*/
                if(split[0]=="login" && split[1]!="ok"){

                sessionid = new String();
                Alert.show(this, Alert.IC_INFO, "Login", "Sorry Fail.. check your user name or password");

                    }               
                    /*live trade */
                    if(split[1]=="2"){
                    curentCode = "2";
                        var change:Number = split[17] == 0 ? 0 : split[6] - split[17];
                    var obj:Object      = new Object();
                    obj.header         =  split[0];
                    obj.type           =  split[1];
                    obj.seqno          =  split[2];
                    obj.time           =  FormatTime.getFormattedTime(split[3]);
                    obj.stock          =  split[4];
                    obj.board          =  split[5];
                    obj.last           =  split[6];
                    obj.lot            =  split[7];
                    obj.buyer          =  split[8];
                    obj.buy            =  split[9];
                    obj.seller         =  split[10];
                    obj.sell           =  split[11];
                    obj.bestbid        =  split[12];
                    obj.bestbidlot     =  split[13];
                    obj.bestoffer      =  split[14];
                    obj.bestofferlot   =  split[15];
                    obj.tradeno        =  split[16];
                    obj.previous       =  split[17];
                    obj.change         =  change;
                    obj.percent        =   Number((change * 100 ) / split[17]).toFixed(1);

                    if(livetradeData.length < limitLivetrade){
                    livetradeData.addItem(obj);
                    }else{
                    livetradeData.removeItemAt(livetradeData.length-1);
                    livetradeData.addItemAt(obj,0);
                    }
                    livetradeData.refresh();

                    }
                    if(split[1]=="6"){
                    curentCode = "6" ;
                IndicesSectoralData = IndicesSectoral.setIndicesSectoral(split,IndicesSectoralData);
                IndicesSectoralData.refresh();

                }
                if(split[1]=="TSBB"){
                curentCode = "TSBB";

                var obj:Object      = new Object();
                obj.header         =  split[0];
                obj.type           =  split[1];
                obj.seqno          =  split[2];
                obj.min1           =  split[3];
                obj.min2           =  split[4];
                obj.BrokerID       =  split[5];
                obj.min3           =  split[6];
                obj.BuyAvg         =  split[7];
                obj.SellAvg        =  split[8];
                obj.BuyVol         =  split[9];
                obj.BuyVal         =  formater.formatMoneyUnit(Number(split[10]));
                obj.BuyFreq        =  split[11];
                obj.SellVol        =  split[12];
                obj.SellVal        =  formater.formatMoneyUnit(split[13]);
                obj.SellFreq       =  formater.formatMoneyUnit(split[14]);
                obj.ValNet         =  formater.formatMoneyUnit((Number(split[10]) - 

                Number(split[13])));
                obj.TotalVal       =  formater.formatMoneyUnit((Number(split[10]) + 

                Number(split[13])));
                obj.TotalVol       =  formater.formatMoneyUnit((Number(split[9])  + 

                Number(split[12])));
                obj.FreqTotal      =  formater.formatMoneyUnit((Number(split[11]) + 

                Number(split[14])));

                /*header|type|seqno|-|-|BrokerID|-|BuyAvg|SellAvg|BuyVol|BuyVal|BuyFreq|SellVol|SellVal|SellFreq
                ValNet = BuyVal - SellVal
                TotalVal = BuyVal + SellVal
                TotalVol = BuyVol + SellVol
                FreqTotal = BuyFreq + SellFreq
                Diurut Berdasarkan TotalVal*/
                var brokerIndex:int = find.findIndex(brokerData,"BrokerID", split[5]);
                if(brokerIndex != -1){
                    obj.BrokerName       =  brokerData.getItemAt(brokerIndex).BrokerName;
                }               
                var idx:int = find.findIndex(topGainerBrokerData,"BrokerID", split[5]);
                //trace("BrokerID:"+idx+"arr[5]"+arr[5]);
                if(idx == -1){
                    topGainerBrokerData.addItem(obj);
                }else{
                    topGainerBrokerData.removeItemAt(idx);
                    topGainerBrokerData.addItemAt(obj,idx);
                }


                ArrayCollection. */
                //topGainerBrokerData.sort = numericDataSort;
                topGainerBrokerData.refresh();


                }
                /*broker */
                if(split[1]=="4"){
                curentCode = "4";
                brokerData = Broker.setBroker(split,brokerData);
                brokerData.refresh();
                }
                /*Stock */
                if(split[1]=="3"){

                curentCode = "3";
                var objStock:Object             = new Object();
                objStock.header                 =  split[0];
                objStock.type                   =  split[1];
                objStock.seqno                  =  split[2];
                objStock.stockcode              =  split[3];
                objStock.stockname              =  split[4];
                objStock.status                 =  split[5];
                objStock.stocktype              =  split[6];
                objStock.sector                 =  split[7];
                objStock.ipoprice               =  split[8];
                objStock.baseprice              =  split[9];
                objStock.listedshares           =  split[10];
                objStock.tradelistedshares      =  split[11];
                objStock.shareperlot            =  split[12];

                var idStock:int = find.findIndex(stockData,"stockcode", split[3]);
                //trace("BrokerID:"+idx+"arr[5]"+arr[5]);
                if(idStock == -1){
                    stockData.addItem(objStock);
                }else{
                    stockData.removeItemAt(idStock);
                    stockData.addItemAt(objStock,idStock);
                }

                }

                if(split[1]=="1"){
                curentCode = "1" ;
                trace("best Quote A:"+data+"\n");
                /* best quote bid */
                var XB:Array = spliter.doSplit(data,"<");
                    var bLotBid:String = XB[1].toString().substring(1,XB[1].toString().indexOf("]")-1);
                trace("bLotBid:"+bLotBid);
                if(bLotBid != ""){
                        bLotBid = bLotBid.substring(1,bLotBid.length);
                        var bLotBidArr:Array = spliter.doSplit(bLotBid,">");
                            var bInt:int;
                            for(bInt = 0; bInt < 10;bInt++){
                            if(bLotBidArr[bInt] != undefined){
                            trace("dipotong :"+bLotBidArr[bInt]);
                var bBidDAT:Array = spliter.doSplit(bLotBidArr[bInt],"|");
                    var obLotBid:Object      = new Object();
                    obLotBid.freq        =  formater.formatNumber(bBidDAT[0]);
                    obLotBid.lot         =  formater.formatNumber(bBidDAT[1]);
                    obLotBid.bid         =  formater.formatNumber(bBidDAT[2]);
                    bestQuoteBID.addItem(obLotBid);
                    }

                    }               

                    }

                    /* best quote bid */    
                    /* offer */
                    var bOFF:String = 

                    XB[1].toString().substring(XB[1].toString().indexOf("O[")+2,XB[1].toString().indexOf("]L"));
                trace("bOFF:"+bOFF);

                var boffArr:Array = spliter.doSplit(bOFF,">");
                    var bIof:int;
                    for(bIof = 0; bIof < 10;bIof++){
                    if(boffArr[bIof] != undefined && boffArr[bIof] != ""){
                        trace("dipotong offer :"+boffArr[bIof]);
                var boofDAT:Array = spliter.doSplit(boffArr[bIof],"|");
                    var obLotBidOFF:Object    = new Object();
                    obLotBidOFF.offer         =  formater.formatNumber(boofDAT[0]);
                    obLotBidOFF.lot           =  formater.formatNumber(boofDAT[1]);
                    obLotBidOFF.o             =  formater.formatNumber(boofDAT[2]);
                    bestQuoteOFFER.addItem(obLotBidOFF);
                    }
                    }


                    }                   
                    // best Quote B //

                    if(split[1]=="TP"){
                curentCode = "TP";
                trace("best Quote TP:"+data+"\n");

                //header|type|seqno|stock|board|price|T.Lot|T.Freq
                var objTp:Object             = new Object();
                objTp.header                 =  split[0];
                objTp.type                   =  split[1];
                objTp.seqno                  =  split[2];
                objTp.stock                  =  split[3];
                objTp.board                  =  split[4];
                objTp.price                  =  formater.formatNumber(split[5]);
                objTp.Tlot                   =  formater.formatNumber(split[6]);
                objTp.Tfreq                  =  formater.formatNumber(split[7]);
                bestQuoteTFREQ.addItem(objTp);
                }
                /* stock summary */
                if(split[1]=="5"){
                //curentCode = "5" ;
                var objStcSum:Object                = new Object();
                objStcSum.header                    =  split[0];
                objStcSum.type                      =  split[1];
                objStcSum.seqno                     =  split[2];
                objStcSum.code                      =  split[3];
                objStcSum.board                     =  split[4];
                objStcSum.remarks                   =  split[5];
                objStcSum.previous                  =  split[6];
                objStcSum.highest                   =  split[7];
                objStcSum.lowest                    =  split[8];
                objStcSum.closing                   =  split[9];
                objStcSum.change                    =  split[10];
                objStcSum.tradedvolume              =  split[11];
                objStcSum.tradedvalue               =  split[12];
                objStcSum.tradedfrequency           =  split[13];
                objStcSum.individualindices         =  split[14];
                objStcSum.foreigner                 =  split[15];
                objStcSum.opening                   =  split[16];
                objStcSum.bestbid                   =  split[17];
                objStcSum.bestbidvolume             =  split[18];
                objStcSum.bestoffer                 =  split[19];
                objStcSum.bestoffervolume           =  split[20];
                stockSummarayData.addItem(objStcSum);




                var idStockSum:int = find.findIndex(stockSummarayData,"code", split[3]);

                if(idStockSum == -1){
                stockSummarayData.addItem(objStcSum);
                }else{
                stockSummarayData.removeItemAt(idStockSum);
                stockSummarayData.addItemAt(objStcSum,idStock);
                }
                }
                /* market chart */
                //trace("COMPOSITE-->"+split[1]);
                if(split[0]=="CHI" && split[1]=="COMPOSITE"){
                curentCode = "COMPOSITE";


                //trace("split[1]:"+split[1]+"split[2]:"+split[2]+"split[3]:"+split[3]+"split[4]:"+split[4]);
                var mrc:Array = spliter.doSplit(split.toString(),"\n");

                    if(split[2]!= null){
                    var o:int;
                    for(o = 0;o < (mrc.length -1);o++){

                    var dtmrc:Array = spliter.doSplit(mrc[o],",");

                var objMcht:Object                = new Object();
                if(o == 0){
                objMcht.time                      =  FormatTime.getFormattedTime(dtmrc[2]);
                objMcht.timeUnformat              =  dtmrc[2];
                objMcht.type                      =  dtmrc[3];
                objMcht.value                     =  dtmrc[4];  
                trace("mrc[o]"+mrc[o]+"== dtmrc:"+dtmrc[0]);
                trace("dtmrc[2]"+dtmrc[2]);
                trace("MARKET CHART time 0-->"+FormatTime.getFormattedTime(dtmrc[2]));
                }else{
                objMcht.time                      =  FormatTime.getFormattedTime(dtmrc[0]);
                objMcht.timeUnformat              =  dtmrc[0];
                objMcht.type                      =  dtmrc[1];
                objMcht.value                     =  dtmrc[2];
                //trace("dtmrc[0]"+dtmrc[0]);
                //trace("MARKET CHART time1-->"+FormatTime.getFormattedTime(dtmrc[0]))+"-->value-->"+dtmrc[2];
                }

                marketChartData.addItem(objMcht);


                }
                //time|type|value
                }   
                marketChartData.refresh();

                }

                }

                public function onSocketData(event : ProgressEvent) : void {
                busyIndicator = true;
                var msgdataTemp:String = new String();
                var n:int = socket.bytesAvailable;
                var bArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                try{
                        //trace("n "+n.toString());
                        while(n > 0){
                        var p:int = socket.bytesAvailable;
                        var s:int = new int();
                        if(sTemp == 0){
                        if(p > 0)
                            p = socket.bytesAvailable;
                            try{
                            s = socket.readInt();//total
                            }catch(e:EOFError){
                            trace("err :"+e);
                            break;
                            }
                            p = socket.bytesAvailable;

                            //trace("bArray"+bArray.toString()+" s:"+s.toString()+" "+p);
                            if(s > p){
                                var bytex:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                                socket.readBytes(bytex,0,p);
                                tempDataSocket.writeBytes(bytex,0,bytex.length);
                                sTemp = s;
                                break;
                            }
                        socket.readBytes(bArray,0,s);
                        bArray.uncompress(CompressionAlgorithm.ZLIB);
                        checkTipe(bArray.toString());
                        n = n-( 4+ s);
                        }else{

                        if(sTemp > p){
                        //bArray.writeBytes(tempDataSocket,0,bArray.length);
                        socket.readBytes(bArray,0,p);
                        tempDataSocket.writeBytes(bArray,0,bArray.length);
                        // trace("sTemp > p  sTemp :"+sTemp+" S :"+s+" p:"+p+" n:"+n+" "+tempDataSocket.length);
                                        sTemp = sTemp +s;
                                        if(sTemp == tempDataSocket.length){
                                            tempDataSocket.uncompress(CompressionAlgorithm.ZLIB);
                                            checkTipe(tempDataSocket.toString());
                                        }

                                        break;
                                    }

                                    //trace("sTemp :"+sTemp+" S :"+s+" p:"+p+" n:"+n+" tempDataSocket :"+tempDataSocket.length+" bArray.length:"+bArray.length);
                        var bnew:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                        if(socket.bytesAvailable > 0){
                        socket.readBytes(bArray,0,(sTemp - tempDataSocket.length));
                        }

                        //tempDataSocket.writeBytes(bArray,tempDataSocket.length,bArray.length);
                        //bnew.writeBytes(bArray,sTemp
                        bnew.writeBytes(tempDataSocket,0,tempDataSocket.length);
                        bnew.writeBytes(bArray,0,bArray.length);

                        bnew.uncompress(CompressionAlgorithm.ZLIB);
                        //trace("bnew:"+bnew.toString());
                        checkTipe(bnew.toString());
                        tempDataSocket = new ByteArray();
                        n = socket.bytesAvailable;
                        sTemp = 0;

                        }

                        p = socket.bytesAvailable;
                        if(p>0){

                        }


                        }


                }catch(ev:Error){
                trace("socket_error:"+ev.getStackTrace());          

                }finally{

                }
                }
                public function resetData():void{
                    sessionid = "";
                    msgdata = "";
                    busyIndicator = false;
                    livetradeData = new ArrayCollection();
                    IndicesSectoralData = new ArrayCollection();
                    topGainerBrokerData = new ArrayCollection();
                    brokerData = new ArrayCollection();
                    stockData = new ArrayCollection(); 
                    marketChartData = new ArrayCollection(); 

                    bestQuoteDataA = new ArrayCollection();
                    bestQuoteDataB = new ArrayCollection();
                    bestQuoteBID = new ArrayCollection();
                    bestQuoteOFFER = new ArrayCollection();
                    bestQuoteTFREQ = new ArrayCollection();
                    stockSummarayData = new ArrayCollection();

                    tempDataSocket = new ByteArray();
                    sTemp = new int();

                    curentCode = "";//current code for unscribe
                    buffer = new ByteArray();
                    _data = new ByteArray();

                    websocketData  = "";
                    isLogin = false;
                }

                public function trim( s:String ):String
                {
                return s.replace( /^([\s|\t|\n]+)?(.*)([\s|\t|\n]+)?$/gm, "$2" );
                }
                private function removeBufferBefore(pos:int):void {
                if (pos == 0) return;
                var nextBuffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                buffer.position = pos;
                buffer.readBytes(nextBuffer);
                buffer = nextBuffer;
                }

                public function unSubscribe():void{
                if(curentCode != null && sessionid  != null && curentCode != ""){
                    try{
                    socket.writeMultiByte("unsubscribe|"+sessionid+"|"+curentCode,"iso-8859-1");
                socket.writeByte(0xff);     
                socket.flush();
                }catch(e:flash.events.ErrorEvent){
                Alert.show(this, Alert.IC_INFO, "Sorry..", e.text);
                    }
                    }
                    }           
                    public function sendData(data:String):void{
                    busyIndicator = true;
                    unSubscribe();
                    socket.writeMultiByte(data,"iso-8859-1");
                    socket.writeByte(0xff);     
                    socket.flush();
                    trace("sendData:"+data);

                }
                public function connect(useridx:String,passwordx:String) : void {
                busyIndicator = true;
                userid   = useridx;
                password = passwordx;
                trace("userid:"+userid);
                trace("password:"+password);
                socket.connect(db.getItemAt(0).defauldIpAdress, db.getItemAt(0).defauldPort);
                //threadedSocket();
            }


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:ViewNavigator label="Main" backgroundColor="0x000"  id="mainview" width="100%" height="100%" 

                     firstView="views.login" icon="@Embed('assets/home.png')"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Menu" backgroundColor="0x000"  width="100%"  height="100%" firstView="views.MenuView" 

                     icon="@Embed('assets/menu.png')"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="about" backgroundColor="0x000" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.aboutView" 

                     icon="@Embed('assets/info.png')"/>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <!--<mx:NumberFormatter
        decimalSeparatorFrom="."
        decimalSeparatorTo="."
        precision="-1"
        rounding="none|up|down|nearest"
        thousandsSeparatorFrom=","
        thousandsSeparatorTo=","
        useNegativeSign="true|false"
        useThousandsSeparator="true|false"/>-->

        <mx:NumberFormatter id="fortmar1" precision="6"
                            rounding="none"
                            decimalSeparatorFrom="."
                            decimalSeparatorTo="."
                            thousandsSeparatorTo=","
                            thousandsSeparatorFrom=","
                            useThousandsSeparator="true"
                            useNegativeSign="true"
                            />

    </fx:Declarations>

</s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication>
```

Comment: That is a whole lot of code .. could you perhaps narrow it down a bit?

Comment: Yeesh, that formatting is hard to follow.

Answer (score 1):

If you are stuck with an old version of the flash player, you need to search google for "Green Threads in AS3".

If you are using a newer version of the player, or Adobe AIR for desktop and devices, multithreading, via "actionscript workers", is available.